# ConcurrentHashMap - do we synchronize methods which access the map

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java and Multithreading.

I have created the below class where I am using `ConcurrentHashMap`. I understand that `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe.
But what about the `startTime` and `endTime` methods.

Do I need to synchronize the `startTime` and `endTime` `APIs`?

```
class ProfileStatistics
{
    private static final ProfileStatistics s_instance = new ProfileStatistics();
    Map<Long, Long> mp                                = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    static ProfileStatistics getInstance()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    synchronized void startTime() throws InterruptedException
    {
        mp.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    synchronized long endTime()
    {
        long tId       = Thread.currentThread().getId();
     
        if(mp.containsKey(tId))
        {
            long start = mp.get(tId);
            mp.remove(tId);
         
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Basil do u mean that if thread calls startTime and then dies without calling endTime. In that case, threadId might be reused?

Comment: I see that now. Thanks. I withdraw my Comment.

Comment: By the way, I think you’ll want to replace the calls to `System.currentTimeMillis` with `System.nanoTime`. And I would return a `Duration` object from `endTime` rather than a mere `long`.

Comment: By the way… Since you have to call this class from the beginning and ending of your code in each task, what does this class really gain you? Couldn’t you just do `long start = System.nanoTime();` and `Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( start - System.nanoTime() ) ;` at the top and bottom of your task code?

Comment: The profiling code is to used at many places. The whole purpose of writing the class is to encapsulate it and maybe if required enhance the class in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the thread id as the key to the Map, you do *not* need to synchronise these methods, because two threads will never try to use the same key. You *do* need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, because two threads modifying a `HashMap` or other non thread safe `Map` concurrently is not safe.

If it was possible for two threads to have the same id, you would need to think about `endTime`.

For the sake of argument, imagine that two threads (thread1 and thread2), both having the same id, call `endTime` simultaneously.

Both threads can call `mp.containsKey(tId)` and see a return value of `true`.

Then one thread might `get` and `remove` the value.

Then the second thread will get a `NullPointerException` when it tries to unbox the result of `get`.

Comment: Great observation @tgdavies – the line `mp.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), ..)` will isolate writes, a bit like a separate namespace.